# How to set value in string resources

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a TextView which take a value from string resources.

```
<string name="versionCode">beta version [version]</string>
```

I want to set a value from code.
I hope you will understand me :)

How can I do that ? It is possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming  `version`  an `int`, you can use

```
<string name="versionCode">beta version %d</string>
```

and in your code, you can do

```
val version: Int = 100
getString(R.string.versionCode, version)
```

you can find the documentation for the overloaded version of `getString` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...))

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
yourTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.versionCode) + yourInt);
```